# Remove all dataframe columns that have a sum lower than given value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` where some columns have very small elements. I want to remove these columns based on the sum of the elements. If the sum is below 1.0, then I want to drop the column. Now I am trying this:

```
df = df.loc[:, (df.sum() < 1.0).any(axis=0)]
```

But it does throw an error that just says "True". Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change mask by inverting mask by `>=` and remove `any`:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.sum() >= 1.0]
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, ~(df.sum() < 1.0)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
df.drop(df.columns[df.sum().lt(1)], axis=1)
```